# How to modify PHP FTP upload script to download files instead

Tags: php, ftp

I have found a PHP script for transferring FTP files, and it works exactly as I need for one part of my project. The script can upload files via FTP to another server just fine, and can output the progress as it goes.

The code I am using is:

```
   $fp = fopen($local_file, 'r');
   $conn_id = ftp_connect($source_ftp_server);
   $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $source_ftp_user_name, $source_ftp_user_pass);
   $ret = ftp_nb_fput($conn_id, $remote_file, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
   while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
       // Establish a new connection to FTP server
       if(!isset($conn_id2)) {
           $conn_id2 = ftp_connect($source_ftp_server);
           $login_result2 = ftp_login($conn_id2, $source_ftp_user_name, $source_ftp_user_pass);
       }

       // Retreive size of uploaded file.
       if(isset($conn_id2)) {
           clearstatcache(); // <- this must be included!!
           $remote_file_size = ftp_size($conn_id2, $remote_file);
       }

       // Calculate upload progress
       $local_file_size  = filesize($local_file);
       if (isset($remote_file_size) && $remote_file_size > 0 ){
           $i = ($remote_file_size/$local_file_size)*100;
                   printf("%d%% uploaded<br>", $i);
                   flush();

       }
       $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);

   }


   if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED) {
       echo "<span style='color:red;'><b>There was an error uploading the file...</b></span><br>";
       exit(1);
   }
    else {
        echo "<br>Files successfully uploaded!<br><br>";    
    }

   fclose($fp);
```

I took out some unimportant parts, such as extra information that is echoed by the script, etc.

This code works perfectly for uploading files to the other server. However, I also need to download a file from the server using FTP as well.

I'd really like to use the same code as above, with the progress indicator, etc, but am not sure how to modify this code to download a file instead of uploading one.

It may be a couple of simple changes are all that is needed.

Are there any parts of this code in particular that will need to be changed, or can this not work the same for downloads as it does for uploads?

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in somewhat of the right direction to sort this out.

Is it as simple as changing the ftp_nb_fput command to a ftp_nb_get command? I don't really understand all of this code so it's difficult to tell what would need to be changed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Although I really understand your quest for help, you should realise by now (considdering your reputation), that SO is not ment to do your job for you. SO is to help you with code that doesn't work. With problems you can't figure out yourself on things you've tried. So try searching for tutorials on the web about PHP FTP clients. Learn from those and work something out. Then, if problems arise, you can ask questions about it here.

Comment: I'm not sure why this attitude is so prevalent on SO. When you read the SO intro info, it says "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions". Nowhere on that page does it say you are expected to spend hours trying to figure things out on your own first. Society was built largely in part because people share knowledge. I'm sure you have asked questions in your lifetime, that people have answered for you, without telling you to go figure it out on your own. This opinion seems to go against everything that is said here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: When you read that page it makes SO sound like a place where people are willing to help if you have questions. However, it seems many people have the attitude that the best help is "go figure it out yourself". That doesn't seem like the way SO was meant to be, from the info they post on their website. I didn't ask for anyone to re-write all of my code, but even some guidance on what part I need to be looking at would help. I've always believed that if I can help someone, I should. I have never given people attitude that have asked me for help.

Comment: @SherwinFlight As you quoted, "ask questions, get answers, no distractions"...  You didn't really ask a question here.  You posted some code barely relevant to want you want to do, and asked someone to figure it all out for you.  If you were completely stuck on how to proceed and knew specifically what you wanted to do, we could give pointers.  Better yet, if you narrowed down your question to a specific question, we could help with a nice specific answer.  Instead, it you've posted a lot of information but left it unclear what the problem is and how we can help you.  This isn't productive.

Comment: I have answered quite a few questions on other Stack Exchange site, like Pro Webmasters, with no trouble at all. I'm always willing to help out when I can. Yet it seems like when I ask for help all I get is attitude, and I'm really not sure why.

Comment: Brad, how much more specific can I get. I said the script currently uploads a file via FTP, I need it to download one. Don't worry about it, even though there are all sorts of people on SO that can provide some guidance in a matter of seconds, I'll just spend a couple of hours figuring this out on my own. Thanks for the "help".

Comment: @SherwinFlight They are telling you why, you just aren't listening.

Comment: @SherwinFlight You're misunderstanding the desire to truly meaningfully help, and a bit of a push to get us there, with an attitude of not wanting to help you.  That couldn't be further from the truth.  The fact is, while you've been probably looking at your code all afternoon and know in your head exactly what you need help with, we don't have such context so you need to be careful to over-communicate and be specific.  Finally, consider your question from the context of someone having the same problem later on.  Does your question (and hopefully answer) help them?

Comment: It is not about "attitude". It's about being helpfull to you in the first place. If I want to properly answer your question, I have to explain in detail how all of it works. It would become an entire book. You can clearly read more about it here: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Aside from that, it would be my approach to your problem. There are different ways to do what you want, making multiple answers possible, which on SO is known as "To Broad".

Comment: @SherwinFlight Start with this... where is your code to do the download?  I see no attempt on your part for this information, so we might as well post a link to the PHP documentation on the matter:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php  Does that documentation help you?  Of course not... if it did, you wouldn't be posting your question.  So, how could we be of more help?  There's already an example on the documentation, and countless examples online.  Explain how your situation is different so we can help you specifically.

Comment: @SherwinFlight " I don't really understand all of this code so it's difficult to tell what would need to be changed." You really should understand the code before using it in your projects, if for nothing more than to be sure it's not doing something you don't want it to do.

Comment: @SherwinFlight Regardless, just look up FTP commands and you should be able to sort it out: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_ftp.asp

Comment: The thing is I don't even understand the code well enough to figure it out without spending hours at it, which is why I asked for help in the first place. Is it as simple as changing the ftp_nb_fput command to a ftp_nb_get command? If I change that, do the other parts need to be changed? Does the part that calculates the progress need to be updated? I really don't know. I haven't worked with FTP via PHP before. That's why I asked for some guidance. This was a place to ask for help, I need help understanding how to modify this code. SO is the only site I know to ask about this stuff.

Comment: @timgavin Please don't refer to w3schools.. you should know that's an unreliable resource :P

Comment: @SherwinFlight Try it and see.  Work through your problem step by step and debug step by step.  A comment based on your approach in general... you realize that FTP is incredibly insecure and problematic in the first place, yes?  Credentials are sent plain text, multiple TCP connections are required, etc.  Unless you had a specific reason to use FTP, and to do a file transfer in your application (stream pass-through, flow control, etc.), I would simply use SCP via shell/exec.

Comment: Anyways, I'll get back trying to figure it out. But this will really make me second think spending my time answering questions for others on Stack Exchange in the future. People have asked questions much more vague than this, and received answered without a problem. I've never had a problem helping others, because I assumed that when I needed help someone would help me. Not so it seems. And I am well aware of the insecurities in FTP, there is a specific reason for using it in this case.

Comment: @SherwinFlight You SHOULD be spending hours at it - otherwise how are you going to learn how to be a good developer? Do you really want to do half-assed, insecure projects for people (and charge them) because you were too lazy to learn and just wanted shortcuts? That's how people get hacked.

Comment: @icecub I know. I know. I could have linked to PHP's site, but that's deep stuff for somebody who is already beyond frustrated. :)

Comment: This is not for anyone else. It's for personal use, for something I really didn't want to spend hours doing. Maybe a good idea to keep your assumptions to yourself if you are just making a wild guess. I'm not a programmer. I don't code for money.

Comment: @SherwinFlight You're right. I shouldn't assume - and I get upset when others do that on this site. I apologize for that.

Comment: A lot of members here had the same problems you're facing right now. Ofcourse it's a lot easier and faster if someone more experienced does the job for you. But what did you really learn from that? What will happen the next time you need something more complicated? Programming is all about hours of frustration, trial and error, and a LOT of learning in the beginning. But you'll get past that! And that's where the fun starts and you'll be developing your own systems all over the place :) But if you don't want to learn and it's just for personal use, why not simply download some working script?

Comment: It's ok, it's not a big deal. Just a bit frustrated because I'm not a developer, and don't sell any of this stuff to others. It's something I'm working on for personal use, and I don't have a lot of free time to spend on it. I have found it much easier to learn from examples. By comparing code, and seeing how they work differently, It's much easier to understand than reading through all the PHP documentation. Some people learn with book easier, some learn better with examples. I just find it easier to compare two pieces of code than to learn how every  piece of it works by reading the DOCS 1st

Comment: I always look at the code, and the PHP documentation, to see what the functions do, and how they work. It's just easier to start with an example, or some guidance, and then work backwards through the code. It's just easier for me that way.

Comment: I also found that when I take a situation like this and break it down into smaller parts, and then ask about the smaller parts, I get told to go look it up still. So one time my question is too open ended, another time too specific they they say it won't help others. Kind of hard to figure out where that sweet spot is in the middle where people will actually try to help. This is a hobby for me, it's personal, I'm not trying to make money from code people on SO help me with, not at all. I make no money from any of the code I write.

Comment: So why don't you search tutorials on the web? They almost always provide you with a download of the finished script, and the tutorial explains you how it works step-by-step. I understand reading the PHP website can be overwhelming and complicated. It feels like it's directed to people that already know how it works, they just want a reference. But tutorials are different. They are directed to human beings like a teacher is teaching his students.

Comment: Also, making money from code that people helped you with on SO isn't a bad thing. No one (at least the decent members) here will look down on you for that. In the end it's a job and it's perfectly normal to make a living of it.

Comment: I used a tutorial to put this script together. However the tutorial was specifically for file uploads. Would FTP_FINISHED also be "true" if I were downloading a file instead of uploading? Online I found this: http://www.thinbasic.org/public/applications/thinbasic/onlyforyoureyes/HTML/index.html?ftp_finished.htm which is useless, and this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-fput.php which mentions it as a return value from the ftp_nb_fput command. But what is it? Is it set for uploads and downloads, or just uploads. Some of this is hard to find online.

Comment: Same with FTP_MOREDATA

Comment: Those are basicly flags for that specific function. If the function returns `FTP_FAILED`, it means the upload failed. If it returns `FTP_FINISHED`, it means the upload is done. If it returns `FTP_MOREDATA`, it means the upload is still in progress (hence the while loop). Now if you take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-get.php (the download function), it returns the same values / flags and also have the same meaning.

Comment: Ok, I'm just gonna play around with it and see how it goes. Sorry if I was a bit frustrated, been awake for like 35 hours or so and was trying to get this finished up while I waited to go home. Been a very very long day.

Comment: We're all frustrated from time to time. As long as you don't become disrespectfull, most here don't mind. Just keep in mind that although sometimes you're not getting what you want, it doesn't mean we don't want to help you. We simply want you to learn it the right way so that in the future, you don't require help for it. And just like you did right now, asking about those return values, is specific and answerable without writing an entire book. That is asking a good question :)

Comment: Thanks for your help icecub :)  I'm working on this script now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the script, with the necessary modifications to make it download a file instead:

```
   $fp = fopen($local_file2, 'w+');
   $conn_id = ftp_connect($source_ftp_server);
   $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $source_ftp_user_name, $source_ftp_user_pass);
   $ret = ftp_nb_fget($conn_id, $fp, $remote_file2, FTP_BINARY);
   while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
       // Establish a new connection to FTP server
       if(!isset($conn_id2)) {
           $conn_id2 = ftp_connect($source_ftp_server);
           $login_result2 = ftp_login($conn_id2, $source_ftp_user_name, $source_ftp_user_pass);
       }

       // Retreive size of source file.
       if(isset($conn_id2)) {
           clearstatcache(); // <- this must be included!!
           $remote_file2_size = ftp_size($conn_id2, $remote_file2);
       }

       // Calculate download progress
       $local_file2_size  = filesize($local_file2);
       if (isset($remote_file2_size) && $remote_file2_size > 0 ){
           $i = ($local_file2_size/$remote_file2_size)*100;
                   printf("%d%% downloaded<br>", $i);

       }
       $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);

   }

   if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED) {
       echo "<span style='color:red;'><b>There was an error downloading the file...</b></span><br>";
       exit(1);
   }
echo "<br>Files successfully downloaded!<br><br>";

   fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Well done. +1 for putting time and efford in doing this yourself!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `ftp_get`

Looks like it should be used something like the following:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($source_ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $source_ftp_user_name, $source_ftp_user_pass);

$success = ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. From what I read it seems like the ftp_get command is similar to the ftp_nb_get command, except that the latter is non-blocking. I'm just going to have to play around with it a bit I think. My main thing is that I assume that the other functions in my While loop will also need to be modified as well, since they originally were for file uploads. I've never had to use FTP via PHP before, so not really sure how the functions all work. Looks like there's only going to be one way to figure this out...  Thanks for your help though, it's appreciated very much.